# If $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ show that the complex function $z^{\alpha}$ is holomorphic and that $(z^{\alpha})'=\alpha z^{\alpha-1}$ without chain rule

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

If $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ show that the complex function $z^{\alpha}$ is holomorphic and that $$(z^{\alpha})'=\alpha z^{\alpha-1}$$

We don't have the chain rule for complex functions yet.

I showed that it is holomorphic using that it's a composition of holomorphic functions, since $z^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha \log (z)}$.

I know that for a complex function $f(z)=u((x,y))+iv((x,y))$, where $z=x+iy$, we have $f'=u_x+iv_x$ and i was trying to prove that way and i got to $$z^{\alpha}=|z|^{\alpha}(\cos(\arg(z)+i\sin(\arg(z))=(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)+i\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)\right)$$

$$=\displaystyle\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1}} + i\frac{y}{x}\displaystyle\frac{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x^2}+1}}$$

but i couldn't move from here and it feels like the
wrong path, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably note *where* it is holomorphic. It certainly isn't holomorphic at $0$ for most choices of $\alpha$, for instance.

Comment: Yeah, this depends on the definition of $z^{\alpha}$ and on what set it is defined.

Comment: It's holomophic in all of $\mathbb{C}$ except for the non-positive numbers in the real coordinate, right? Since this is the domain of $\log z$ and the definition is $z^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\log z}$. But how does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\,\alpha\,$ be a complex number $\,\big(\,\alpha\in\mathbb C\,\big)\,$.

The function $\,z^\alpha\,$ is defined for every $\,z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,$ in the following way :

$z^\alpha=e^{\alpha\ln z}\quad$ for any $\,z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,.$

There are two cases :

$\alpha=0\quad$ or $\quad\alpha\ne0\,.$

If $\,\alpha=0\,,\,$ then $\,z^\alpha=1\;$ for any $\,z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,,$

consequently ,

$D_{z=z_0}\,z^\alpha=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\dfrac{z^\alpha-z_0^\alpha}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\dfrac{1-1}{z-z_0}=0=\alpha z_0^{\alpha-1}$

for any $\,z_0\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,.$

If $\,\alpha\ne0\,,\,$ then

$D_{z=z_0}\,z^\alpha=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\dfrac{z^\alpha-z_0^\alpha}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\dfrac{z_0^\alpha\left[\left(\dfrac z{z_0}\right)^\alpha-1\right]}{z_0\left(\dfrac z{z_0}-1\right)}=$

$\quad=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\dfrac{z_0^{\alpha-1}\left[\left(\dfrac z{z_0}\right)^\alpha-1\right]}{\dfrac z{z_0}-1}=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }\,w=\frac z{z_0}-1}}{=}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{z_0^{\alpha-1}\left[\left(1+w\right)^\alpha-1\right]}w=$

$\quad=z_0^{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha\ln(1+w)}-1}w=$

$\quad=z_0^{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{e^{\alpha\ln(1+w)}-1}{\alpha\ln(1+w)}\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{\alpha\ln(1+w)}w=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{by letting }\,u=\alpha\ln(1+w)}}{=}\alpha z_0^{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{u\to0}\dfrac{e^u-1}u\lim\limits_{w\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+w)}w=$

$\quad=\alpha z_0^{\alpha-1}\cdot1\cdot1=\alpha z_0^{\alpha-1}$

for any $\,z_0\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,.$

Hence , in any case , we get that

$D_{z=z_0}\,z^\alpha=\alpha z_0^{\alpha-1}\quad$ for any $\,z_0\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\,.$